# Quickest route to get up to speed with iPhone development

Tags: iphone

Am currently reading Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Hillegass just to get up to speed on Objective-C and the Development tools. What would be the next best step ?

Instructor led course ?
Online training?
Specific books ?

Answer (score 4):

I can't ever learn a new development platform without a programming project.

I would pick a simple project that will touch on a bunch of different design and interface elements - and go to it...

-t

Comment: Programming is like math. You can't really learn it just by reading about it. You have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

My recommended approach, especially with iPhone development, is 'learning by doing'.

I'd say you should get your hands dirty with a simple app, like "Hello World". 
Next step would be to improve on it, making a simple flashlight app (display a image). You'd then improve on it by adding some dynamic text, etc.

Recommended resources:
http://appsamuck.com/ - really simple apps you can code in less than an hour, explained in detail

iPhone Development books: "iPhone Developer's Cookbook" and "Beginning iPhone 3 Development" (get them on Amazon)

Answer (score 1):

[CS193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) is an excellent resource with all the lectures and homeworks.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning iPhone 3 Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK is a nice book.

Answer (score 0):

I would pay a cheap freelancer.com to help me out via a remote desktop method. There are out there people who are experienced and for some money they will teach you.